# How to use NDepend to split a shared assembly?

Tags: .net, ndepend

I am working on splitting up a repo among multiple, mostly separate sub-projects. There is one large project that all the projects reference. I am looking for a way to get a list of classes in the shared project that are only used in one of the sub-projects, so as to build a candidate list of classes that could be removed from the shared project. The end goal is that the shared project only contains shared code.

I can do a lot of this using reflection, but I have an NDepend license, and it seems like this is something I should be able to do using NDepend. How would I do this using NDepend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single [CQLInq code query](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL)

```
let myAsm = Application.Assemblies.WithName("YourAsmName").Single()
from a in Application.Assemblies where a.IsUsing(myAsm)
select new { 
   a, 
   typesUsed = myAsm.ChildTypes.UsedBy(a) }
```

et voilà!

[image: NDepend lists types usage]

Certainly the [NDepend dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm) can help as well, first export assemblies users to matrix **columns**.

[image: Export Assemblies to NDepend Dependency Matrix]

second export your assembly types to matrix **rows**, this can be with such code query, just export result types to **rows** this times,

```
let myAsm = Application.Assemblies.WithName("YourAsmName").Single()
from t in myAsm.ChildTypes select t
```

and now you can explore all the dependencies, and dig into them.

[image: NDepend Dependency Matrix]

Of course you can refine these code queries to get exactly what you need in query result and on matrix.

If you have a few dozens of assemblies and types, you can try exporting to the [NDepend dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) instead of exporting to the matrix, but it might look messy with too many nodes, the matrix is more adapted to deal with many nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!